# How to stop "Failed to delete the temporary file..." warnings from VS2012 compiler

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have two rather large solutions that both experience the same problem.  The issue is that I am warned about an inability to delete temporary files.  The messages all look like this:

> Failed to delete the temporary file
>   "C:\Users\Don\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp07197280428445c484ba0cda58178903.exec.cmd".
>   The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Don\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp07197280428445c484ba0cda58178903.exec.cmd'
>   because it is being used by another process.

I have seen suggestions of using pre-build commands to first delete things, but that is a lot of projects, and I'm not going there.

Anyone know how else I might remedy this, that does not involve "fixing" each project individually?

If it makes any difference, I'm compiling C# .NET 3.5 projects.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is, to write a small addin for Visual Studio, which can delete files on build. You could configure it with filepaths and then just run sth like this:

```
foreach (var item in paths)
    File.Delete(item);
```

And the config you could put solutionwide.

Comment: Interesting thought.  But wouldn't that be dangerous since the path in my case is `C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp`?  Meaning that anything system-wide trying to work there while a build is happening could be affected?

Comment: I meant that you should put in the paths to the files, not the folder. The other option is, to use subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

I get that too - the problem is that the compilation system itself is holding onto the file when it attempts to delete it. I think it deletes it afterwards anyway as I've never seen the named files hanging around afterwards so its just an annoyance that can be ignored.

The files seem to be the command that VS is running that is built up from the build settings.

I assume its a .NET thing where the GC hasn't cleaned up the object that has the handle to the file when the system attempts to delete it. If so, directly shows the benefit of RAII over GC :-)

Comment: I agree that it seems harmless, except that it clogs up my error/warning list and makes it hard to spot things that really deserve my attention.

Comment: I know, I know.... but I haven't found a way to get rid of it. I do use VSColorOutput extension that lets me colour the output contents according to what really is an error or a warning, so I can grey that error out and it isn't so noticeable. It will still appear in your Error List window though :(

Comment: Thanks for the VSColorOutput tip.  Nice extension.

Answer (score 0):

A likely source for the problem is that your antivirus software is busy scanning the file in question, which prevents the rightful owner deleting it.  Curb the enthusiasm of the antivirus and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Unload the project from your solution, than reload it. It should create the missing files and be buildable again.

Answer (score -1):

If you have installed any third party cleaner tool and activated the active mode (always running in background) this will lock the temp folder in the appdata so Visual Studio is unable to restore the Nuget package on build and there will be a build error.

Try uninstalling the cleaner and restarting the system. When I had this problem, that was how I fixed it.